# error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘TOKEN’

Tags: c

Basically this is a program which I take a text file with some code and take each char and make it a token or make the other chars that are included in it become a token like a variable. That part works I know because I have used this code for another project and I'm just reusing. The problem is that when I am trying to get the token the scanner.c  create and return it to another file it is saying I have an error "error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘TOKEN’". I cant figure out where the error is. Here is my scanner.c file and I also posted the .h file where the token is defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.h"


*TOKEN parseString(char *token);
*TOKEN parseChar(char token);

*TOKEN scan(FILE *input_file)
{    
   int stateTable[3][122];
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   for( i=0; i < 3; i++)//init to 0
   {
      for ( j=0; j < 122; j++)
      {
         stateTable[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }

   for( i=48; i < 57; i++)//all numbers [0-9]
   {
      stateTable[1][i] = 3;
      stateTable[3][i] = 3;
   }

   for( i=97; i < 122; i++)//all alpha [a-z]
   {
      stateTable[1][i] = 2;
      stateTable[2][i] = 2;
   }

   stateTable[1][10] = 1;// \n
   stateTable[1][32] = 1;// space
   stateTable[1][40] = 1;// (
   stateTable[1][41] = 1;// )
   stateTable[1][42] = 1;// *
   stateTable[1][43] = 1;// +
   stateTable[1][45] = 1;// -
   stateTable[1][47] = 1;// /
   stateTable[1][59] = 1;// ;
   stateTable[1][61] = 1;// =

   int state = 0;
   int index = 0;
   char temp[20];
   char token;


      token = fgetc(input_file);
      state = stateTable[1][(int) token];

      if (state == 2 || state == 3)//num or alpha
      {
         temp[index] = token;
         index++;
          scan(input_file);
      }
      else if (state = 1)
      { 
            if (index >= 1)//digit or identifier
            {
                temp[index] = '\0';
                return parseString(&temp[0]);
                temp[0] = '\0';
            }   
            else
               return parseChar(token);

            if(token == ';' ||token == ')')
                return parseChar(token);

            index = 0;
      }

}

*TOKEN parseString(char *token)
{
    TOKEN *temp = malloc(sizeof(TOKEN));
    if(strcmp("repeat",token) == 0)
        &temp.type = 4;
    else if(strcmp("print",token) == 0)
        &temp.type = 5;
    else if(isdigit(token[0]))
    {
        &temp.type = 12;
        &temp.attribute = token[0];
    }
    else if(strcmp(token, "") != 0)
    {
        &temp.type = 10;
        &temp.attribute = token;
    }

    return temp;
}

*TOKEN parseChar(char token)
{   
    TOKEN *temp = malloc(sizeof(TOKEN));
    if(token == '+' || token == '-')
    {
        &temp.type = 14;
        &temp.attribute = token;

    }
    else if(token == '/' || token == '*' || token == '%')
    {
        &temp.type = 13;
        &temp.attribute = token;
    }
    else if(token == '=')
        &temp.type = 3;
    else if(token == ';')
        &temp.type = 17;
    else if(token == '(')
        &temp.type = 15;
    else if(token ==')')
        &temp.type = 16;

    return temp;

}
```

Here's the parser.h file that has the TOKEN in it described.

```
#ifndef _parser_h
#define _parser_h


typedef enum token_type
{
    Id,
    keyword,
    num,
    addOp,
    multOp,
    assignment,
    semicolon,
    lparen,
    rparen

}TOKEN_TYPE;

typedef struct token{
    TOKEN_TYPE type;
    char* attribute;
}TOKEN;

typedef enum node_type
{
    PROGRAM,
    statement,
    assignStmt,
    repeatStmt,
    printStmt,
    exp,
    term,
    factor
}NODE_TYPE;

#endif
```

It just keeps saying where ever I declare the function name that I am missing a '(' before the TOKEN.

Any help would be great.

Comment: That got rid of the missing'(' error but now its not recognizing my token.type or token.attribute

btw thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be
    TOKEN* parseChar(char token)
instead of
    *TOKEN parseChar(char token)

and 
    temp->type = 4;
instead of
    &temp.type = 4;

Answer (score 1):

As said: it should be `TOKEN*`.

But you also have to fix some other issues.

```
TOKEN *temp ;
```

`temp->type` or `(*temp).type` instead of `(&temp).type`